# react-google-maps calls empty InfoWindow

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have problem with first call InfoWindow, it calling like 2 times and one have not any text/info and the second infoWindow have correct my info (number 2 on-screen). If I will click to another my Markeк this empty InfoWindow will stay in the first place. But if I will try to close the empty window and open any my marker this empty window will shows again in a new place.

[image]

[image]

my code:

```
    function MapCreator() {
  const [selectedPoint, setselectedPoint] = useState(null);
  const [data,setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('api/coordinates')
    .then(values=>{
        console.log(values.data);
        setData(values.data);
    })
    const listener = e => {
      if (e.key === "Escape") {
        setselectedPoint(null);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("keydown", listener);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", listener);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={14}
      defaultCenter={{ lat: 50.444571, lng: 30.559099 }}
    >
      {data.map(park => (
        <Marker
          key={park._id}
          position={{
            lat: park.coordinates.latitude,
            lng: park.coordinates.longitude
          }}
          onClick={() => {
            setselectedPoint(park);
          }}
          icon={{
            url: nfcIcon,
            scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(60, 60)
          }}
        />
      ))}

      {selectedPoint && (
        <InfoWindow
          onCloseClick={() => {
            setselectedPoint(null);
          }}
          position={{
            lat: selectedPoint.coordinates.latitude,
            lng: selectedPoint.coordinates.longitude
          }}
        >
          <div>
                <h2>Device ID: {selectedPoint.identificatorNFC}</h2>
                <p>Date: {new Date(selectedPoint.date) .toUTCString()}</p>
          </div>
        </InfoWindow>
      )}
    </GoogleMap>
  );
}

const MapWrapped = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(MapCreator));

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: `100%`, height: "100vh" }}>
      <MapWrapped
        googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=${
        keys.googleApi
        }`}
        loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        containerElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tbh, I don't see any kind of problem in your code but I suggest try this out:

```
  function MapCreator() {
  const [selectedPoint, setselectedPoint] = useState(null);
  const [data,setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('api/coordinates')
    .then(values=>{
        console.log(values.data);
        setData(values.data);
    })
    const listener = e => {
      if (e.key === "Escape") {
        setselectedPoint(null);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("keydown", listener);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", listener);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={14}
      defaultCenter={{ lat: 50.444571, lng: 30.559099 }}
    >
      {data.map(park => (
        <Marker
          key={park._id}
          position={{
            lat: park.coordinates.latitude,
            lng: park.coordinates.longitude
          }}
          onClick={() => {
            setselectedPoint(park);
          }}
          icon={{
            url: nfcIcon,
            scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(60, 60)
          }}
        >
         {selectedPoint && selectedPoint._id === park._id && (
           <InfoWindow onCloseClick={() => setselectedPoint(null)}
           >
             <div>
                <h2>Device ID: {selectedPoint.identificatorNFC}</h2>
                <p>Date: {new Date(selectedPoint.date) .toUTCString()}</p>
             </div>
           </InfoWindow>
         )}
        </Marker>
      ))}

    </GoogleMap>
  );
}

const MapWrapped = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(MapCreator));

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: `100%`, height: "100vh" }}>
      <MapWrapped
        googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=${
        keys.googleApi
        }`}
        loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        containerElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: {selectedPoint && selectedPoint._id === park._id && (
           <InfoWindow/>

I forgot this part of code, my code doesnt check is selected point equals to element in .map loop

Comment: In your code, InfoWindow was not inside the marker as well.

Comment: Thanks!  The key for me was <Marker ... /> --> <Marker ...></Marker> and moving the <InfoWindow> code within <Marker>

Answer (score 0):

I used `InfoWindowF` instead of `InfoWindow` and it solved this issue for me